Can a parent take things an adult son/daughter owns or was given while living with the parent?
In the US, specifically in the state of Tennessee, can a parent take the property of their adult son/daughter while they live with their parents? For example someone buys a phone and gives it to them: can the parent take it away?

Why would you think parents would have the right to take property away from an adult child just because they are also their landlord?

@nick012000 I think the obvious answer is that there may be a belief that the parents can engage in this behavior as a condition for providing rent-free room and board.

"someone buys a phone and gives it to them" is not very clear. Who is "someone" and who is "them"? Why would it even matter how the son/daughter got the phone?

As already noted in the comments by nick012000 and bdb484, first, the fact that the parents are the landlords of the adult child as such gives them no right to the property of the child.
One could try to argue that there is implicit rental contract between parents and child where the parents provide the room for no direct monetary compensation but instead retain the right to confiscate valuable property of the child as payment.
While I assume one could make a contract of that form (with some limit to the total value to be confiscated that represents the rent) I don't think any assumption that the implicit agreement between adult children and parents should be interpreted that way would hold in court.

"You live in my house, you live by my rules" is a common way that parents express this implied contract.

Out where I live we have trespass of movable property which involves unlawfully interfering with or damaging someone's movable property. It's a wrong against the right of possession of the plaintiff. I just checked the trespass laws in Tennessee and I dont see any clauses about trespass of movable property so I'm not sure about the legal proceedings one can take on this offence

Welcome to the Stack! I think you might be on the verge of a good answer here. The querent has tagged this question with Tennessee, but we generally accept answers from other jurisdictions as a matter of course so folks can see how laws vary. To do this, can you preface your answer with the tag for where you live and provide a citation to the relevant law that you are referencing?

The question isn't about damaging the property, it's about taking it. That seems like simple theft.
