Is it legal for a parent to confiscate items from their child who is over 18?
Can a parent legally confiscate items (e.g. electronic devices) from a child who is over 18 years old?

In the UK, theft can only be committed with the intention of permanently depriving the other of their property. Assuming the confiscation you refer to is temporary, this could lead to a civil claim for interference with the child's property rights, such as conversion or trespass to goods.

Of course, the scenario you present is very broad. For example, is the child still permanently living with their parents? Was the confiscated item being used in a way that the parents had prohibited on their property?

Possible duplicate of https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/105314/can-a-parent-take-things-an-adult-son-daughter-owns-or-was-given-while-the-live

Things might be different also when the confiscated items are illegal per se (e.g. joints)

I'm pretty sure they cannot just drive across the country, march across the lawn, break down their child's door and grab whatever they want. You have a different scenario in mind, right?

@FD_bfa "permenantly depriving" might not always mean what you think. Treating an item as your own to dispose of with no intention to permanently deprive can be sufficient as can borrowing in some circumstances. An example of the former is R v Lavender [1994] Crim LR 297 in which the defendant took a door from a council property and gave it back by placing it on another council property. An example of the latter could be taking a cinema ticket with the intention of giving it back after the show when it's lost its value.

Yes, in general statute is never quite as simple as interpreting it at face value. But I don't believe the exceptions you mention are relevant to what the OP has in mind. It is almost always the case that borrowing will not constitute theft. @JBentley

@JBentley the ticket probably has a cash value of 0.1¢ or something like that.  The thing of greater value is the service one can obtain by showing the ticket, of attending a particular showing -- and once the movie has been shown, the thief has permanently deprived the rightful bearer of the ticket of the opportunity to attend that showing.

@phoog The point here is that because of the way the law is drafted, you can commit theft of the actual physical ticket by borrowing it, your points notwithstanding. You'd be charged with that rather than charged with causing the person to miss the show.

france
In France, there cannot be any theft between children and their parents (or between two spouses). It's not that the parents are allowed to confiscate things, there is a blanket immunity from criminal prosecution in article 311-12 of the Code pénal, in both directions (parents to child but also child to parent). The underlying logic is that this is something families should sort out between themselves, not through the justice system.
There is however a recently added exception to this long-standing principle: You are not allowed to remove “things that are indispensable to day-to-day life like ID documents […] means of payment or telecommunication”. So basically, taking away your adult child's mobile phone is very likely to be prosecutable as theft, a cooking or self-care appliance, probably not. The exception for ID and means of payment was added in 2006, the reference to “means of telecommunication” in 2015. (There are other caveats not relevant to this question, e.g. for married couples who are legally separated).
Interestingly, it's the exact opposite of the principle described in Dale's answer: This is based entirely on the family relationship, whether the adult child lives together with his or her parents or, say, get financial assistance from them doesn't matter.

"Their game console" needs a case-by-case analysis. My son uses his console as means to talk to his friends on a popular game platform and even organize IRL meetings. It is a means of telecommunication.

@MindwinRememberMonica Thanks for the comment, I think it's a bit of a stretch in this context but I was just looking for an example, I tried another one.

"In France, there cannot be any theft between children and their parents": regardless of age, of whether the child is s minor, or of whether the parent and child share a household?  Does this mean that an 80-year old parent cannot be prosecuted for stealing from her 60-year-old child?  Even if she went into his house without permission?

@phoog Yes, that's exactly what it means, at least not for the theft itself. Entering without permission may constitute a separate offense, depending on the circumstances.

Wow!  Now I just need to get my mother to Paris with as much cash and jewelry as she can fit into her suitcase, and I can retire! :-)

@phoog A civil case is not out of the question, the “family immunity” only rules out criminal prosecution (and also applies to a bunch of other offenses like fraud, blackmail, providing shelter to a criminal, helping someone stay illegally, not denouncing a crime…). I edited the answer slightly to make the distinction between criminal and civil proceedings clearer.

Not based on just the parent-child relationship
However, if the child is a guest in the parents’ home, the parents can impose conditions - implicit or explicit  - on the child continuing to be welcome there.

(+1) Not sure why it was downvoted. Explaining where this applies could be useful, though, in France it's exactly the other way around.
